# IE11 Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

How to force IE11 (as a user) to always show the status bar - regardless of what the website developer has configured?

In IE9 we could force visibility of the status bar by disabling the security setting "Allow websites to open windows without address or status bars". This setting still exists in IE11, however, it does not seem to have any effect.

What's the solution for IE11?

[context information: for our Selenium test suite it is essential that Internet Explorer windows have the status bar enabled (so that whenever the cursor hovers over a link it does not show the URL in a yellow tool tip but instead shows the URL in the status bar).]